# Not able to pass Meteor.settings json file

Tags: node.js, meteor

On my local workstation, I can easily load my settings by passing --settings which works perfectly fine. For my dev/production server, I following the documentation AND a few postings here which have me create a file.json file with what i want to pass. I have a script which passes the export commands properly and then fails to pass my meteor settings.

METEOR_SETTINGS=$(cat /var/www/html/dev/dev.json)

Am I missing something? Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

figured out the answer to this

when you run a script, you need to export METEOR_SETTINGS just like you would export the mongo url and port 3000.

Simple but overlooked based on replies from other posts.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you bundled your application for production? 
For me the following did the trick

```
export METEOR_SETTINGS="`cat settings.json`"
```